# How to set Date type variables to initial value?

Tags: swift, date

I can't find the way to set Date type variables to initial or empty value(not use a user defined initial value...like '0001/01/01').

Like String type can set String.init() or "" to it's value, so can use isEmpty() to determine it is empty, but how to do that with Date type variables?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are going to accomplish.

Naturally there is no *empty* date.

- If the value of the date is irrelevant declare it with the current date

  ```
  let date = Date()
  ```
- If the date is supposed to be quite unspecified in the distant past or future there are

  ```
  let date = Date.distantPast

  let date = Date.distantFuture
  ```
- If the date can be a specific date use the reference dates

  ```
  let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0) // 1970/1/1

  let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // 2001/1/1
  ```

Comment: I am against using current date as a placeholder. I already seen too many bugs caused by that. It's better to use `nil`.

Comment: @Sulthan What's worse, the current date or the optional?  *I already seen too many bugs caused by* optionals. 

Comment: I have seen people to use `Date()` as a default when parsing a date fails. Then an invalid date was shown to the user and they did not even notice :) I think `Date()` shouldn't be used in situations where we want to really say "there is no meaningful date".

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `Date` object by its default constructor.

```
var date = Date()
```

The above line will initialize the `date` object with the current date.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `Date = nil`
Which means when we assign a value to data like

```
var date = Date() // means its current data
```

**OR else**

Use following codes to set a date from string format

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "2016-02-29 12:24:26") {
    print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date))
} else {
   print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that there is no empty `Date`.

A `String` has 3 possible states:

1. there is some string, e.g. `"abc"`
2. there is an empty string, that is, `""`
3. there is no string, that is, `nil`.

With strings, case 2 and 3 are usually interchangeable. That means that we can use either an empty string or `nil` to mean the same.

There are no empty `Date` values, therefore if we want to represent the state when there is no `Date`, we *have to use* `nil`.

```
var date: Date? = nil
```